# BiodiversityR package failing to load

Tags: r, namespaces, install.packages

I'm trying to load the BiodiversityR package and getting the following error and warning messages:

```
library(BiodiversityR)

Loading required package: tcltk
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘pbkrtest’ 0.4-2 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.4 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘BiodiversityR’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘BiodiversityR’
```

I don't understand what it means/what I need to do to fix it. Can anyone please help? Thank you!

Comment: Try uninstalling pbkrtest and reinstalling it with all dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but it doesn't help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant part of the error message is this:

```
Error … : 
  namespace ‘pbkrtest’ 0.4-2 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.4 is required
```

— Your package (indirectly) depends on another package called ‘pbkrtest’. This package is installed but apparently outdated. You need to reinstall it using `install.packages('pbkrtest')`.

The additional warning message gives a hint about the source of this error: you updated R after installing some packages. You may need to reinstall all packages after upgrading R. In fact, the warning suggests that it’s probably a good idea to also reinstall the ‘BiodiversityR’.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. However, when I try to reinstall pbkrtest I get another warning message:

'Warning in install.packages: package ‘pbkrtest’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)'

Comment: @RBeginner That’s bizarre but the solution for that is to upgrade R to version 3.3: then it will work (I tried it).

Comment: After lots of uninstalling and reinstalling its now working and I even have the latest version of R! Thanks again!